# Logit link notation

Tags: self-study, logit, notation

Here is the whole question:

> (a)A Simulation Study (Logistic Regression). Assume $y|x \sim \mathrm{Binary}(p)$,
>   where $p= \mathrm{E}(y|x)$, and $\mathrm{logit}(p_i)=-1+5.1x_{1i}-0.3*x_{2i}$. Generate data
>   with $x_{1i}\sim \mathrm{Unif}(0,1)$, $x_{2i}=1$ for $i$ odd and $x_{2i}=0$ for $i$ even, and sample size $n$=500.  Try generalized linear model (GLM) with logistic and probit
>   links. What’s your finding?

We are required to use R to do it. I am not familiar with the notations like $y|x\sim\mathrm{Binary}(p)$,where $p= \mathrm{E}(y|x)$, and $\mathrm{logit}(p_i)=-1+5.1x_{1i}-0.3*x_{2i}$, with $x_{1i}~\mathrm{Unif}(0,1)$ ,$x_{2i}=1$ for $i$ odd and $x_{2i}=0$ for $i$ even,and sample size $n$=500.

Also how to use to generate $x_1$ and $x_2$?

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you be clearer about what you don't understand & need to know? This appears to be instructions for generating simulated data for a problem or simulation study of some sort. Is this an assignment for a class you are taking? If so, please add the `[self-study]` and read its wiki. Are you supposed to actually do this? What software do you use? (Nb, asking for code is off-topic, but it might be helpful to know nevertheless.)

Comment: Can you be more specific about which parts you need help with? Do you know what $\sim$ means there, for example?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would implement those instructions in Stata:

```
set obs 500
gen x1 = runiform()
gen x2 = mod(_n,2)
gen p  = invlogit(-1 + 5.1*x1 -0.3*x2)
gen y  = runiform() < p
```

My R is a bit rusty, but here is my go:

```
library(boot)
x1 <- runif(500)
x2 <- (1:500)%%2
p  <- inv.logit(-1 + 5.1*x1 -0.3*x2)
y  <- runif(500) < p
```

Comment: It is always delightful to see a pithy solution expressed so naturally in well-crafted code.  However, (a) only a small minority of readers will know Stata and (b) I believe the O.P. would appreciate some more explicit explanation of how your code is related to the notation she is seeking to understand.

Comment: @whuber I intentionally did not give such details as this is a self-study question. It is a hint, not a full answer. I find it usually helps to know where I should end up, in order to fill in the steps in between.

Comment: Stata arcana: `gen` means "generate" or calculate; `_n` is the observation number, in this case the vector 1(1)500. `mod(y,x)` returns the remainder on division of y by x, e.g. `mod(3,2)` is 3 modulo 2 or 1.

Comment: What (1:500)%%2 means?

Comment: it means exactly the same as `mod(_n,2)` in the Stata code, see @NickCox 's comments on that.